# Handler.postDelayed causes lag

Tags: java, android, performance, android-handler

I created an application that can call using our SIP server. Now I want to do is to show the user how long his call has been on going. My script is actually working but I noticed that the longer the call, the laggy my app becomes. Here's the snippet of my code

```
Handler h = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
_isOnCall = true;
long time = 0;
int x = 0;

while(_isOnCall) {
     if (_isOnCall){
         final int counter = 1 + x;
         time += 1000;
         h.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
             @Override
             public void run() {
                 (TargetDetailsActivity.this).runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                     @Override
                     public void run() {
                         final int seconds = counter % 60;
                         final int minutes = (counter % 3600) / 60;
                         final int hours = counter / 3600;

                         callcounter.post(new Runnable() {
                             @Override
                             public void run() {
                                 callcounter.setText(String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", hours, minutes, seconds));
                             }
                         });
                     }
                 });
             }
         }, time);
         x++;
     }else{
         break;
     }
}
```

Basically what the code does is just to count the seconds/minutes/hour he's been on the phone. When he hangs up, I call the code below:

```
_isOnCall = false;
h.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
```

I'm not sure what causes the lag. Help! Thanks.

**UPDATE**

I was able to make this working by utilizing galvan's suggestion using Timer. Here's my code for future reference:

```
private Timer myTimer;
private int counter_time=0;

public void onCallEstablished() {
    myTimer = new Timer();
    myTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            TimerMethod();
        }

    }, 0, 1000);
}

private void TimerMethod()
{
    this.runOnUiThread(Timer_Tick);
}

private Runnable Timer_Tick = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        counter_time++;
        int seconds = counter_time % 60;
        int minutes = (counter_time % 3600) / 60;
        int hours = counter_time / 3600;

        callcounter.setText(String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", hours, minutes, seconds));
    }
};


public void releaseCall(){

    if(myTimer != null){
        myTimer.cancel();
        myTimer.purge();
        counter_time = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: is the while loop running on the ui thread ?

Comment: @Blackbelt uhm sorry I don't exactly know what you mean about UI thread. I'm very new to android. :(

Comment: @user3360031: Post the complete code. Is this code written in the UI thread???

Comment: @V_J the code is pretty long. But to give you an idea, it's in my activity class.

Comment: Handler  and postDelayed are better used for small operations, of supposingly 2 seconds. Make your own thread for this operating. You can make own Thread or can use an Executor. 

Google about Executor and Handler. You will get plenty of examples.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like every Runnable saves a reference to his parent object, a nested Runnable in this case. Try to take an heap snapshot for detecting a memory issues to see if this is the case here.

You can also make a repeat task with time interval, and stop the loop when the call ends.

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
TimerTask myTask = new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // whatever you need to do every 2 seconds
    }
};

timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(myTask,
                       firstTime,
                       period);
```

for more info about timer you can take a look at the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html#scheduleAtFixedRate(java.util.TimerTask,%20java.util.Date,%20long))

Comment: Thank you for this input. I was able to make it working using Timer. Please see  my updated post.